# Errors when compiling GLR parsers from Happy - 'parse error on input ‘case’'

Tags: haskell, happy, glr

I have tried multiple example grammars and get the same error when I try to compile the generated files.

For example I have followed exactly the solution to this question - [GLR_Lib.hs: Could not find module 'System'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736442/glr-lib-hs-could-not-find-module-system)

where the grammar file is

```
%tokentype { ABC }
%error { parseError }
%token 
    a { A }
    b { B }
    c { C }
%%
s1 : a a a b {} | b s2 a {}
s2 : b a b s2 {} | c {}
{
data ABC = A | B | C deriving (Eq,Ord,Show) 
parseError _ = error "bad"
}
```

But when I compile I get:

[1 of 2] Compiling ABCData       ( ABCData.hs, ABCData.o )

[2 of 2] Compiling ABC         ( ABC.hs, ANC.o )

GLR_Lib.hs:164:2: parse error on input ‘case’

This exact error has happened with every grammar that I have tried. I don't know what I could be doing differently to people that have the examples working successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indentation errors in the `GLR_Lib` template. This is what I did to get it to work:

1. Create the `ABCMain.hs` file.
2. Create a new directory `./templates` for the edited templates.
3. Find the originals - e.g. use `locate GLR_Lib`. On OSX with the Haskell Platform I found them in /Library/Haskell/current/share/happy-1.19.4/
4. Copy all of the templates to `./templates`
5. Make the following edits to `./templates/GLR_Lib`:

   - line 44: comment out `import System`
   - line 161: replace the leading space with a tab: `case new_stks of`
   - line 190: replace the leading space with a tab: `stks' <- foldM (pack i) stks reds`
6. Run: `happy --glr --template=./templates ABC.y`
7. Compile with: `ghc --make ABCMain`

You will probably only need the `GLR_Lib` and `GLR_Base` templates.